# I'm better when I lie all the time than some of the time

Tags: riddle

When I'm a complete truth-teller, you're happy with me
When I'm a complete liar, I'm still doing my job very well 
When I'm mostly a liar, you know there's something seriously wrong with me

**Who am I?**

Comment: Probably not the intended solution, but could you be a [princess](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29364/the-three-princesses-distinguishing-truth-teller-with-1-question)?

Comment: I immediately thought a lawyer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are

> a clock

because when I'm a complete truth-teller, you're happy with me:

> Accurate clocks are a good thing.

When I'm a complete liar, I'm still doing my job very well:

> A clock that is as off as possible (i.e., 12 hours), is still very useful for telling the time since we don't usually need a clock to know whether it's AM or PM.

When I'm mostly a liar, you know there's something seriously wrong with me:

> Any clock that's neither accurate nor exactly 12 hours off does not function as a useful clock.

Comment: I would say "complete liar" is a clock that keeps accurate time, but is not set to the correct time. The only way the time can *always* be wrong is if the hands advance at exactly the right speed. If the clock gained or lost time, it would occasionally have the correct time ("mostly a liar").

Comment: I object... why "complete liar" imply "always off by a constant amount"? Can't you have a clock which wobbles unpredictably but which advances *on average* at the correct rate so that it is never actually correct?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain is correct about my thinking behind the "complete liar clue".

Comment: @Mehrdad no not really, clocks like the one you're describing don't exist in reality so it's a purely hypothetical possibility, whereas the possibility of a clock that functions properly but is set to the incorrect time (say five minute early) and still serves a useful purpose is a very common thing.

Comment: @user1717828 your third clue explanation is also a bit off, mostly a liar would mean it's sometimes telling the truth.

Comment: @BigBlackBox: I dunno about that, white noise is everywhere...

Comment: A 12-hour clock can be at most off by 6 hours.

Comment: @BigBlackBox I don't see that as being a problem. A stopped clock tells the correct time twice a day. A slow or fast clock would likewise sometimes be correct, unlike a clock with a fixed offset.

Comment: @BigBlackBox, Ok.  Please update the clue explanations as you see fit.  I get much more enjoyment out of solving the puzzle than I do justifying every clue 100% in line with the author's intent.

Comment: I personally see the third clue as being pretty good. Back in Highschool, the class-bell clock was off by about 4 minutes. Knowing that, it was a lying clock, but a complete liar. It was never the right time, however since you already knew he 'lied' you could easily figure out the difference between the real and the fake time, effectively not having a problem with it. The problem would come if that clock wasn't constant, and as such unpredicteable (One day it could be right, the other it could be 10, 5, 2, 8 minutes off mark). As such, if he's mostly a liar it's useless

Comment: The third clue refers to a stopped clock, which tells the truth twice a day, but is completely unusable. Until everybodies clock started syncing with atomic clocks automatically, these clocks were accurate the most often, but you'd still prefer one that is never completely accurate, but actually usuable (like the clock in hint #2)

Answer (score 10):

You are

> A Man / Boyfriend/ Husband

When I'm a complete truth-teller, you're happy with me

> You appreciate my honesty

When I'm a complete liar, I'm still doing my job very well

> No, you're not fat

When I'm mostly a liar, you know there's something seriously wrong with me

> You're not fat, just a little bit chubby

Answer (score 3):

You are an

> answer verifier

when you tell the truth all the time,

> we know that the answer is true or not.

When you lie all the time,

> we again know when the answer is true or not. When you say it is "true", we know it is not and vice versa.

However, when you lie sometimes,

> you are useless and we have no idea if the answer is true or not.

Although,

> You may be a fortuneteller based on the same reasoning.

Comment: I was gonna awnser this question again as a computer / boolean statement, but then realized your awnser covers the same reasoning. Might be worth considering expanding your answer ;)